# Performance: Passing Objects vs Creating New Object

Tags: php, performance, object

I'm looking for a best practice. In general would you get better performance from passing an object or creating a new one from the database? For example:

```
$someObject = new SomeObject();
SomeObject::some( $someObject );

public static function some( $someObject ) {
   //Do something with the passed in object
}

//or...

public static function some() {
   $someObject = new SomeObject();
   //Do something with the newly creataed object from database
}
```

My thought is anytime you can refrain from calling the dB you will get better performance, but not sure if there are any quirks with passing an object instead.

Comment: Creating a new object inside your function makes it harder to unit test; whereas if you pass the object to the function, it can easily be mocked for unit testing

Comment: Further from @MarkBaker's comment - it also means that if you want to change `$someObject` for `$someOtherObject`, you can just change it at the point where you instantiate the class that contains `some()`, rather than having to update it inside the class itself. This is the concept of the class containing `some()` not needing to know anything about `SomeObject`, it just gets passed it and uses it.

Comment: Great feedback guys. What is your perspective on performance?